# The visual studio code terminal highlights in light blue after windows 10 update

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

The issue is that my terminal in vs code highlights in a horrible light blue. This happened after my Windows 10 machine updated.

I have already tried setting the terminal colours in the settings, I've changed the command line, tried cmd and powershell, and they both highlight. I've also disabled all of my plugins.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help people in the future, I found that it was most likely to do with a windows update, it was for some reason linked to the background colour of my command prompt, so I set that to black and it no longer highlights as seen in the image.

Hope this helps people in the future.

Comment: This didn't work for me. My node.js command prompt was set to blue background, so I set it black. Running npm build inside VS Code(1.37) Terminal I still get the blue highlighting, but inside Node.js command prompt it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I still have this issue as of VS Code Version 1.34.0
I'm modifying settings (while using a Dark Theme) as a workaround

```
{
    'workbench.colorCustomizations': {
        'terminal.ansiBlue': "#191919"
    }
}
```

I do not understand the need to re-assign ansi-colours :( , but it works for me.